# XMPP chat sent/received message synchronization

Tags: c#, xmpp, openfire, agsxmpp

**Scenario**: I am trying to develop a web site which features a chat widget. I am using ASP.NET, C#, agsXMPP library as my tools in achieving this purpose. I use Openfire jabber server for XMPP server.

**Problem**: When I access the widget on the website and start chatting, I send a *message* with message type "chat" and *thread* set. I receive this message on the client in this case Spark. When I reply to this message, I see that the *thread* value is not the same as the one I sent? According to [RFC 3921 section 2.1.2.3](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html#stanzas-message-children-thread), **The value of the  element is generated by the sender and SHOULD be copied back in any replies.**
However, I don't see this happening.This means, I cannot link the response with the message I sent.

Can anyone help me with what I am missing? The following is the message sent and received.

> **Sent Message**: `<message type="chat" to="saurabh@127.0.0.1/spark" id="agsXMPP_6" from="gantir@127.0.0.1/CPWebchat"><thread>d6ddeebe-f23f-4854-a315-2a9de32906b8</thread><subject>Ramjee Ganti</subject><body>An Anonymous user via the web is attempting to contact you. Name: Ramjee Ganti Email: xxx@example.com Issue: Sample Test</body></message>`
>
> **Received Message**: `<message id="BTqN4-34" to="gantir@127.0.0.1/CPWebchat" from="saurabh@127.0.0.1/spark" type="chat"><body>Hello</body> <thread>42MtKq</thread><x xmlns="jabber:x:event"><offline/>  <composing/></x></message>`

Answer (score 1):

The RFC says the "thread" element SHOULD (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119) be returned in replies. It may be that this client just didn't implement it.

Comment: Thanks for this, I did not check the RFC Key word usage earlier. That might be the case.