# google chat web client

Tags: widget

I am looking for a google chat client that I can embed in my website so visitors can chat with me directly.  I haven't found any widgets like the google voice widget in which a visitor is connected directly to you without authentication.  The only authentication I would want would be their name and email address.

Are there any widgets out there that integrate with google chat nicely?

Thanks,
Walter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for the Google Talkback badge:

http://www.google.com/talk/service/badge/New

Note, that in order to use it with Google Apps for Domains, you need to disable the SSL option for your domain while creating the badge, you can reenable it afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.  It looks exactly like what I'm looking for.

Comment: Thanks, you got me 99% of the way there.  This is what I needed:

https://www.google.com/talk/service/a/DOMAIN/badge/New

where DOMAIN = your domain

Answer (score 0):

I am working on developing for my customer, a similar widget which works with XMPP server. And since gtalk is built on XMPP it should work here too.
It is not a very difficult thing to build, can't share the application with you because the app belongs to the client. But can guide you to develop one if you are interested.

I am having one problem which is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715257/xmpp-chat-sent-received-message-synchronization) at stackoverflow. Once I resolve this issue will be happy to share more details.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your comments.  I might in the future; however, this already works and is google-branded.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find a standard Jabber(the protocol GChat uses) client, create an default "user" account and add yourself as a buddy.